# force word docs, pdf, xls, etc to download by clicking on a link with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http-headers

I am trying to get documents(ie. pdf, excel, word doc, etc) to open in a download box. for some reason the excel files work correctly but none of the others do. I think I need to setHeader using javascript(i believe that jquery does not have core functions that do this, but correct me if i'm wrong). here is a sample of my code.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.media-link').click(function(event){
        var fileName = $(this).html();
        var property_id = $("input[name=capturePropId]").val();
        //alert(fileName);
        event.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
        window.location.href = '../uploads/properties/'+
        property_id+'/media/'+fileName+'';
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
        filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    });
});
```

When i do this i get an error "response.setHeader response is undefinded. does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the headers differently for each filetype. Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/FileDownloadUsingJScript.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change server's response with JavaScript and you can't control how browser decides to open a new link outside of chosing this/new window. It is up to server to decide what to return for your request - i.e. it can response with the same JPG image for all requests or any other type of response.

You need to put the code that sets headers on the server that serves the request. You have correct code if your server is ASP.Net one ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519).

Comment: ok i'm with you so far. i guess i'm confused on where in the my php file i need to set the header. maybe my files too comingled with different languages. i have jquery tabs going a jquery slide going all sorts of data being pulled from the data base. this probably doesn't help you better understand why i still cannot not grasp this concept but it might. i understand how to do it your way if i submitted a form but i cannot understand how to set the header for an anchor tag.

Comment: You can NOT set set headers in JavaScript and setting headers on the servers side that generate the page with the link will not help. You need to set this headers on server on the handler for Url that returns the files. In your case it looks like you need to make ../uploads/properties/XXX/media/FILE.NAME Urls to be handled by your server code (PHP) and return file stream with the additional headers.